# Nginx $connections_active per server block

Tags: nginx, proxy, lua

Is it possible to have the $connections_active from the stub nginx per server block? That way i can know how many requests per second each website is doing. This only does for global connections accross the entire proxy. If not how can i do it?

I'm using openresty and lua programming.

Comment: The following 44 lines are doing more than what want: https://framagit.org/snippets/2820 . It should be easy to strip down to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it with nginx&lua:

```
lua_shared_dict live_hosts 1M;

rewrite_by_lua_block {
  local dict = ngx.shared.live_hosts;
  if (not ngx.var.http_counted) then
     ngx.req.set_header("counted", "true");
     dict:incr(ngx.var.host, 1, 0);
  end
}

log_by_lua_block {
  local dict = ngx.shared.live_hosts;
  dict:incr(ngx.var.host, -1);
}
```

You can then access `ngx.shared.live_hosts:get('foo.com')`

NB: the `counted` added header is necessary to handle nginx internal redirect: in that case rewrite_by_lua is called twice whereas log_by_lua is called only once. `ngx.ctx` can not be used (it is cleared in case of internal redirect)

Comment: I've been searching a solution for hours, and idk why google didn't get me here. Thanks btw!